# Should one segregate Domain Objects from Rest of App?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm relatively new to Hibernate and am trying to understand the best architectural approach to designing a DAO.  Initially I created a set of domain (Entity) objects and wrote a DAO interface and impl to access them.  To reduce risk of using the Entities in Collections I wrote equals() and hashCode() methods that did not use the primary keys.  But I found that cumbersome and inefficient.  I then decided to eliminate the issue by confining use of the domain objects to the DAO and using DTO's to send to/retrieve from the DAO.  It struck me that an additional benefit was an abstraction and decoupling of the data sent/retrieved from the table structure.

However, using Hibernate can be cumbersome if one isn't playing with Entity objects to begin with.  EG, a DAO method to write a list of dependent objects in a @OneToMany relationship can no longer be passed an instance of the parent-side entity because while the code using the DAO might have the parent's id, it doesn't have a parent entity to pass.  The relationship must either be removed or made unidirectional or the DAO must do a retrieve of the parent to get an entity reference.

One earlier reply labeled DTO's an anti-pattern.  I can see why.  But with wider use of the Entity classes doesn't the problem of Hibernate identity fields I mention become problematic and potentially dangerous?  Also, are there not other advantages to abstracting the returned data from the table structures such as decoupling?  Since DTO's may be needed anyway if complex sets of data are returned, why not use them 100% of the time and gain the advantages I mentioned?

Comment: Using DTOs in place of entities is an antipattern. Entities are meant to be used in all the layers of the application. DTOs are useful to transfer data over the wire, or to transfer data that is not represented as an entity (an aggregate report for example). Otherwise, use your entities. That's what they're for.